# Java Nested If Help (The Logic is seemingly correct but always outputs the same thing)

Tags: java, if-statement, nested, logic

I am trying to use nested if statements in order to determine the value of a variable and with this code, the correct results are not occurring. Please can someone help? I am using an array to hold values that are being compared to the input (using this in order to show "knowledge" of java). Then, I am calling the function testFlower() to initialize the logic. I am not able to identify where in my logic I went wrong. Every time anything is inputted, the result that is printed out by the print line is always "Roses". This returned String should change when different flower names are typed in but this does not occur. Does anybody have any ideas on the issue in the code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A {

    public final double TAX = 1.127;
    public final double s_basket = 10, m_basket = 20, l_basket = 30, s_elephant = 15, l_elephant = 30, 
             s_seal = 15, l_seal = 30, s_bear = 15, l_bear = 30, s_penguin = 15, l_penguin = 30, 
             mChocolate = 15, wChocolate = 20, dChocolate = 30;

    public String flowers[] = {"ROSE", "TULIP", "DAISY", "DAFFODIL", "SUNFLOWER", "ORCHID"};

    public Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public String flowerType;


    public void testFlower() {
        if (!(flowerType.equals(flowers[1]))) {
            if (!(flowerType.equals(flowers[2]))) {
                if (!(flowerType.equals(flowers[3]))) {
                    if (!(flowerType.equals(flowers[4]))) {
                        if (!(flowerType.equals(flowers[5]))) {
                            flowerType = "Roses";
                            System.out.println(flowerType);
                        } else {
                            flowerType = "Orchids";
                            System.out.println(flowerType);
                        }
                    } else {
                        flowerType = "Sunflowers";
                        System.out.println(flowerType);
                    }
                } else {
                    flowerType = "Daffodils";
                    System.out.println(flowerType);
                }
            } else {
                flowerType = "Daises";
                System.out.println(flowerType);
            }
        } else {
            flowerType = "Tulips";
            System.out.println(flowerType);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();

        System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to my flower shop! What type of flowers do you want? (rose, tulip, daisy, daffodil, sunflower, orchid)");
        a.flowerType = a.s.nextLine();
        a.flowerType.toUpperCase();

        a.testFlower();

    }
}
```

Comment: The values in the array are being tested when they don't match the input. If it sdoesn't match any of the values in the array, automaticly the last nested if statement gets printed. In this case you would always get roses as result. Because "ROSES" is not the same as "ROSE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, learn to use a debugger and inspect values such as `flowerType`. Doing so would immediately have shown you that the uppercasing doesn't do what you expect: You have to assign the result to a variable, since the string is immutable.

```
a.flowerType = a.s.nextLine();
a.flowerType = a.flowerType.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: I used the debugger and was not able to look at the variable. I am using eclipse. Can you explain how?

Comment: The "variables" tab will list the variables that are currently in scope, along with their string representations (which in this case is just the contents).

Comment: you may need to open the debug perspective to get the default set of tabs for debugging including the variables tab mentioned in prior note.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint (double-click on the left margin next to the line `public void testFlower()`) and run in Debug instead of Run mode, it should open automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As chrylis said in the previous answer, your uppercasing is incorrect. But I also would point out that you don't have to use nested if/else statements, since Java has a HashMap class, which can be used with objects as keys. See the following code:

```
public HashMap<String, String> flowers = new HashMap<String, String>();
flowers.put("ROSE", "Roses");
...
flowers.put("ORCHID", "Orchids");

//this code basically replaces your testFlower function.
System.out.println(flowers.get(flowerType));
```

I hope I didn't misunderstand the purpose of your program. In case I did, please disregard my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the values in the array to

```
"ROSES", "TULIPS", "DAISIES", "DAFFODILSS", "SUNFLOWERS", "ORCHIDS"
```

Use a `for` loop instead of nested if-statements (saves a lot of typing):

```
for(int i =0; i < flowers.length;i++){
    if(flowers[i].equals(flowerType){
        system.out.println(flowerType);
        break;
    } else if (i == flowers.length - 1) {
        system.out.println("Unknown flowertype " + flowerType);
    }
}
```

---

Use a parameter for the flower method:

```
a.flowerType = a.s.nextLine();
a.flowerType = a.flowerType.toUpperCase();
a.testFlower(flowerType);
```

---

```
public void testFlower(String f){
    flowerType = f;
    // do something
}
```

Like this your program could work.